# is there any way to send METHOD value in <a> tag

Tags: laravel-controller, laravel-resource

when I send edit request to edit() using `<a>` it's working because of `'GET'`, but for Delete, I have to send a request for  `Delete` Method also, How I can send it without using the form like `edit`

```
<a href="/auctions/{{$auction->id}}/edit" class="btn btn-info">Edit</a>
<form action="{{url('/auctions',$auction->id)}}" method="POST">
        @csrf
        @method('DELETE')
       <input type="submit" class="btn btn-danger"
value="Delete">
</form>
```

I just want to know that we can send METHOD value by `<a>` Or Not

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Clicks on links via `<a href="">link</a>` are always `GET` requests and cannot be anything else.